# Aliasing in C# for use with long property syntax

Tags: c#, wpf, alias

When updating the Text property of a TextBox in WPF, I have to the following, which gets tiresome after a while:

```
window.TokenInfoText.Text += "some text";
```

If I do the following:

```
string textref = window.TokenInfoText.Text;
textref += "some text";
```

it compiles but does not update the Text field of the TextBox at runtime.

Is there a way to "alias" the long syntax (i.e. `window.TokenInfoText.Text`) so that one doesn't have to type as much?

PS: I know about MVVM; what I am after here is a simpler approach specifically to reduce typing.  Something like the "using" statement utilized for namespace aliases, but for regular variables/properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when you access a property into a local variable or field, you're obtaining an isolated snapshot of the value at that moment in time - like looking at the clock on the wall, and writing the time down on a bit of paper. If you read from the copy (paper), it doesn't magically update from the source (clock) - and if you change the value of the copy, it doesn't update the source.

So: that's why it isn't working.

There *is* a concept in properties that allows for what you want: by-ref return properties. These have very niche utility, and have only been in the language for a little while. They also change the shape of the property, so it cannot be used with properties that do not expose themselves this way. But: it *is* possible to do (in the general sense, not this specific case):

```cs
ref string foo = ref {blah some expression}.Whatever;
//
Console.WriteLine(foo); // writes the current value *from the source*
foo = "ABC"; // updates the original source
```

But: this requires a very specific API, meaning: the property must be declared as `ref string` or `ref readonly string`. It is very very rare, not least because it means the containing object no longer has the ability to validate values or enforce any logic - because the caller is going directly to the raw data.

Comment: I attempted to use `ref = ref` construct but it complained that it cannot be placed within an async method.  Given that most all methods have to be async nowadays, I gave up at that point.  I am coming to C# from a C/C++ background and had pointers in mind when I posted the question.  Thank you for your answer, including the first paragraph.

Comment: @Sabuncu there *are* ways to use `ref` semantics inside `async` code, as long as you don't span an `await`; `static` local functions can be very handy for that.

Comment: I see, will try them out.  Again, thank you for your time and the hard-to-find information you provided re: the by-ref return properties.  Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable types, and when you appear to modify a string, what really happens is that you substitue a reference to one string with a reference to *another* string.

When you do:

```
string textref = window.TokenInfoText.Text;
```

you get a copy of the reference to the string returned by the `Text` property. When you later do `+=` on the string, you overwrite the reference in your local variable `textref` with another reference, but the `Text` property is not affected.

However, *if* the getter of the previous property `TokenInfoText` always returns the same reference, then it will work if you go one level less deep, i.e.:

```
var tiText = window.TokenInfoText;
tiText.Text += "some text";
```

In any case, you can go out to the class level and write a property (also recommended by Tarik's answer), and that will work:

```
private string Textref
{
  get => window.TokenInfoText.Text;
  set => window.TokenInfoText.Text = value;
}
```

and then inside your method you can do `Textref += "some text";`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define properties that will get and set the text fields. This will cost you the definition of a property for each field but make the code clearer.

The alternative is to move all the business logic and the associated properties into a separate class completely decoupled from the form. You can then use databinding to bind each field with each property. As property values are changed, it gets reflected in the UI.

In the field data binding attributes, you can specify what to show for null values, how to format numbers and so on.

It's worth the effort to make your code more maintainable and allow reusing the same class in a web or mobile app.

Comment: @Sabuncu This answer is correct and _not_ patronizing.